# How to increase the disk space of Ubuntu installed besides Windows 7?

Tags: 11.04, windows, partitioning, dual-boot, disk-usage

It is true that there are similar questions in the forum... But as I installed Ubuntu under Windows 7 long time ago, I do not remember how I did it or whether I used Wubi, which is discussed in many similar questions.

So the situation is, I had Windows 7 installed on the laptop in the very beginning, then I installed Ubuntu so that this is a dual system (once again, i could not remember how I did it).

Today when I use "Disk Usage Analyzer" to scan the disks. It says:

```
Total filesystem capacity: 303.2 GB (used: 162.2 GB available: 141.0 GB)
```

And the size of root is 161.1 GB whose usage is 100%. It seems that the files under my Windows are all counted in this 161.GB. So now the question is how to make use of the rest 141.0 GB, especially extend Ubuntu space with that.

Could anyone help? Thank you very much.

As suggested, here is some images from Disk Utility: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQbc2.jpg and images from Disk Usage Analyzer https://i.stack.imgur.com/S99fF.jpg , the folder under /media is mounted from Windows (so both Windows and Ubuntu could share it)

Comment: I am not sure whether screenshot of Disk Usage Analyzer would be useful. Better use Disk Utility (aka `palimpsest`) which shows disk partitions. Grab the screenshot which shows your disk, use 'img' button in editor while editing the question or just upload the screenshot to http://imgur.com/ and paste the link.

Comment: I believe you haven't installed Ubuntu with wubi I think you can use a live cd. From gparted.

Answer (score 2):

If the moment you have to select whether to run Windows or Ubuntu, the title on top of screen says "Windows Boot Manager" than you probably have used Wubi and you should follow [this link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1625371).

Try the above link and if it didn't work or you can't or don't want (no time or not interested) to understand what happens in the howto, I would reinstall Ubuntu with more disk space.

PS: Don't forget to save your data when you work with partitions!

Answer (score 2):

If you check in the windows partition to see if there is an Ubuntu folder. Or go to add/remove programs, if Ubuntu is there, then you used wubi. If not then its on a separate partition.

If this is the case, use a live cd, you can adjust the partition sizes with gParted.